Rundeck Failed webhook authorization
I'm trying to use a Rundeck webhook to run a job, I'm using Postman and Curl to try, but in both I'm receiving the message "err: "Failed webhook authorization""
My webhook from my rundeck lab
My webhook from my rundeck lab
My webhook from my rundeck lab
POSTMAN

Why do you use a Bearer token on the "Authorization" header? You can use a specific token generated in the General Webhook Config (by clicking the "Use Authorization Header" checkbox) and call it in a single post-call as follows: curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:4440/api/46/webhook/4EnN0BJp66vyw3dfvPljrq16DcbuI708#MyWebhook' --header 'Authorization: mppFTgfnSGNlDq470vP0ltutOSoMAKLD'

You can use a specific token generated in the General Webhook Config (by clicking the "Use Authorization Header" checkbox) and call it in a single post-call as follows:
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:4440/api/46/webhook/4EnN0BJp66vyw3dfvPljrq16DcbuI708#MyWebhook' --header 'Authorization: mppFTgfnSGNlDq470vP0ltutOSoMAKLD'

